# Blender File Cleanup - remapping users with duplicate data

Tags: import, append, duplicate

I can't seem to locate a way to do just what I want easily, and there doesn't seem to be any add-on utility addressing this, so here goes:

Say I have a file with many materials and meshes, and I want to append some data (scenes, etc) from another file that is using a lot of the same data. An example is that two people are working on the same project, but then want to later merge the two files into one.

Once I append the scenes from the second file, there are many meshes, embedded images, and materials which would ideally be linked and share the same data, rather than being separate (.001,.002,.003,etc). What I want to be able to do with some ease is to remap the users of multiple identical data to a single data block. The filter for determining if data should be remapped cannot be as simple as examining the names and looking for .002, etc. This operation should examine if, for example, meshes have the same vertices and origin point, etc. Likewise for images it should examine file size, or some similar property which would be identical only among true duplicates.

The Material Utilities does have an operation to "Merge Base Names", but that is only for materials, and is problematic because it seemingly only examines the name for comparing if two materials should be remapped into one. If someone makes a variant of a material, doesn't give it some other unique naming identifier but just uses ".002", and changes some aspect of the node tree, then the Merge Base Names operation would lose that change, as it would assume they are meant to be identical.

A further complication is that if you try to do this manually in the Blender File view of Outliner, the remap users menu is unusable when you have a long list of names, since you can't access the list beyond a certain size/length...

Any tips out there for addressing this bloat? It's not just for file size reasons that reusing identical data is important, but also for the sake of future changes to materials, etc, propagating out as they should. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Interesting problem that I might have if I Appended two characters that also use many of the same material (e.g., clothing).   Might you consider keeping the original files and using Linking instead of Append?  That's what I do for my various characters when I create an animation with two or more of them.   Otherwise, I'd imaging some rather complex python script that would identify similarly named materials, and perhaps have to step through each node to verify that each has identical nodes with identical input params (ugh!).

Comment: I think your first sentence is superfluous and would suggest you delete it.

Comment: Linking doesn't really address the workflow issue because within the main file, scenes, etc that are brought in via linking are not editable. I could edit them in the linked file, but then data changes in the main file aren't propagated out to the linked file (material, mesh, image changes, etc). Using library assets for everything would sort of help, but that has to be carefully done from the beginning and isn't a good solution when working quickly or with a distributed team. Unless I'm missing something (?)